# Можно ли отключить авто обновление приложения на андроиде не через Google Play, а через само это приложение? Можно ли это закодить внутри приложения?

Tags: update, android

Есть приложение на Google Play. Мне необходимо отключить его автоматическое обновление. Обновление приложения должно происходить только при определённых исключительных условиях. Было бы идеально добавить опцию внутри самого приложения, которая проверяла бы условия и в случае успеха делалось бы обновление, а в случае провала всё бы оставалось как есть.

Comment: Please translate you question to russian language

Comment: Please translate you question to russian language

Comment: Через свой сервер сделать это можно, но без согласия пользователя обновить не выйдет.

Comment: @pavel, если не трудно можешь объяснить по подробнее как именно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, нельзя. Приложение не решает, может ли оно обновляться само через Googel Play, или не может.
Единственный вариант - распространять приложение **не через Google Play**.
В этом случае, вы можете сделать так, чтобы приложение проверяло, нет ли обновлений на вашем сервере, и загружало обновления согласно вашим пожеланиям.

Comment: Ну или лучше выложить на гугл плей а дальше обновлять со своего сервера, не заливая на гугл. Это же возможно?

Comment: @pavel, возможно, но как по мне - смысла в этом не особо много